# Verb and adjective usage

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, adjectives

Since adjectives are used to describe nouns, can verbs be used to describe nouns as well?

For example:

> Two men standing with clenched fists are US athletes.

Here *fist* is a noun and to describe a noun, an adjective is used. In this case the adjective should be *clenched* but the dictionary shows that *clenched* is a verb.

So does that mean that verbs are also used to describe nouns?

Comment: Verbs have various forms that can be used as adjectives; they're called participles and one kind ends in -ing and the other either looks like a past tense (like _clenched_) or is a different form altogether (like _sung_). So even if a word is being used as an adjective, it can be a verb. Or a noun.

Comment: @JohnLawler -- So, is 'clenched' in the above example is a verb or a noun or an adjective ?

Comment: it's not a noun, but it is a verb form being used as an adjective, so it's both a verb and an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about the word *clenched*: virtually all participles can be used not only in verb phrases alone but also as participial adjectives in noun phrases.

However, you should also keep in mind that not all words that modify nouns are adjectives, nor does modification of a noun automatically make a word an adjective.

In answer to the question posed in comments as to whether in

> Lack of infrastructure facility can be a major cause for under development.

The word *infrastructure* is an adjective or a noun, the answer is that it is
 a noun, not an adjective.

If it were an adjective, it would accept adverbs as modifiers, but it does not: you cannot say *a ∗very infrastructure development* or *a ∗quickly infrastructure development*.

Because it is a noun, it accepts as modifiers either adjectives or other nouns, as in *critical infrastructure development* or *city infrastructure development*.

The adjective corresponding to the noun *infrastructure* is *infrastructural*.

Modifying nouns does not make in and of itself make something an adjective; there are other criteria. Nouns can modify nouns, and so can verbs.

Comment: @oerkelens Length requirements forbid one-bit answers. :)

Comment: @tchrist -- Okay, but how do I recognize a verb, noun or an adjective in a sentence ?

Comment: @tchrist -- consider the sentence 'Lack of infrastructure facility can be a major cause for under development'. Please tell me, is 'infrastructure' an adjective or a noun ?

Comment: @iamRR *Infrastructure* is a noun, not an adjective. If it were an adjective, it would accept adverbs as modifiers, but it does not: you cannot say *a ∗very infrastructure development* or *a ∗quickly infrastructure development*.  Because it is a noun, it accepts as modifiers either adjectives or other nouns, as in *critical infrastructure development* or *city infrastructure development*. See the difference? The adjective corresponding to the noun *infrastructure* is *infrastructural*. Modifying nouns does not make something an adjective; there are other criteria. Nouns can modify nouns.

Comment: @iamRR Please do not add supplementary questions in comments. There are questions here about **attributive nouns;** please research, show your research, and ask another question if you can't find anything (someone will find the duplicate).

Comment: @tchrist -- Thanks for your reply. I looked up many books and I found that adjectives modify nouns. Consider the sentence : "He is a good man". Here adjective 'good' modifies noun 'man'. Similarly if the sentence is : 'Lack of infrastructure development'. So here also infrastructure should be adjective and development should be a noun. I understand 'infrastructure' is a noun but in the above sentence doesn't it act like an adjective ?

Comment: @iamRR It is a noun modifying a noun. If it acted like an adjective, you could apply adverbs to it. But you cannot do that. Instead, you can apply adjectives or other nouns to it. Therefore it is still a noun. ***Just because adjectives modify nouns does not mean that nothing else does so.***

Answer (score -2):

Mr.clenched is both form of words, noun as well as verb. Read meaning of words in full. You may need Google to find meaning use following format

define:clenched

This will show as follows[image: use define:clenched as noun in google]